# Clear existing chart and add new data

Tags: java, teechart

I have created a chart and would like to completely clear it out and re-use it with new data.

How would I go about completely clearing the chart of all series/draw lines etc?

Comment: What have you tried?  You're likely to get more assistance if you show that you have put forth the effort to resolve it on your own.

Comment: When I populate the chart I see the point displayed one at a time. I then call Series.clear(), but the series is not removed from the screen. Then when I re-populate the series it is displayed at once. I would like it to be displayed point by point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below. There's no TChart.clear() method in the Java version as in other TeeChart versions. I have added this (TJ71016243) to the wish-list to be implemented for next releases.

```
tChart1.removeAllSeries();
tChart1.getTools().removeAll(tChart1.getTools());
```

Comment: Thanks. So once I have cleared the chart how do I see the points as they are writen to the chart. At the moment they all appear at once.

Comment: @user1254689 I'm sorry but I'm not sure about what do you mean here. Do you mean populating a chart and see how each point is being added? If that's the case you could use Autorepaint to choose when the chart is being painted as explained in the Real-time Charting article at http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php